# I need to iterate to the end of a column in Java on an Excel Sheet with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi, xlsx

I am iterating down a column of values until it hits a blank. I need to gather the entire column and store it, and no other values. I've attempted to check for blank, null, 0, "", and CELL_TYPE_BLANK (int = 3), and I cannot get it to avoid a null pointer exception. Code snippet and error are below. What can I do? This is not the entire method or program, just the relevant piece.

```
String s = list[i];
//find the directory from the list array to locate the file
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(s);
//create a new workbook object to hold the excel file
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
//create an arbitrary starting location
int column = 2; //absolutely the correct number
int rownum = 10;
//get the value from the first sheet
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet insheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);       
//of the second columm
Row row = insheet.getRow(rownum);
//in the 11th row (arbitrary number used to reduce iterations and skip whitespace)
Cell cell = row.getCell(column); 
System.out.println("Skimming sheet: " + insheet.getSheetName());
//iterate until the very end of the column is found
System.out.println("Cell value B" + (rownum-1) +  ": " + cell);

//3 denotes CELL_TYPE_BLANK
while (cell.getCellType() != 3 ) {
    //go to the next location
    //update to the next cell
    System.out.println("Cell value B" + rownum +  ": " + cell);
    row = insheet.getRow(rownum);
    if(row.getCell(column).getCellType() != 3){
        cell = row.getCell(column); //error occurs here, line 241
    }
    rownum++;
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FileTest.skim(FileTest.java:241)
    at FileTest.main(FileTest.java:121)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gettint the error because the row you're trying to access is null, not the cell. You want to take a look in the [Apache POI Iterator](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) example.

```
//taken from the example
Sheet sheet = wb.getsheetat(0);
for (Iterator<Row> rit = sheet.rowiterator(); rit.hasnext(); ) {
    Row row = rit.next();
    //now, based in your needs
    Cell cell = row.getCell(column);
    //do what you need with the row-column
}
```

Comment: Iterators have always been an enigma to me, but i will give it a shot and see where i can get it.

Comment: When you define a structure like an array, a linked list or a different structure based on array/linked lists, the Iterator provides a way to get each of the elements in an order. For example, in a binary tree the Iterator could traverse the items one by one by using an in-order traversal, providing easy access for the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate rows in a for loop up to last row, that will prevent running in to that exception:

```
 for(int i =0 ; i< insheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
//do stuff
}
```